# rm -rf not working

Tags: linux, rm, delete

I'm trying to remove Anaconda with `rm -rf miniconda3` on Linux. However, when it runs I get as output that it cannot remove things because the directory is not empty
( for example `rm: cannot remove ‘miniconda3/share/terminfo/t’: Directory not empty`)

At the end of it if I run `ls`, I get:

```
ls: cannot access LICENSE.txt: No such file or directory
bin  conda-meta  envs  include  lib  LICENSE.txt  pkgs  share  ssl
```

So it looks like it deleted something, but not most of the things. How can delete everything from the folder

Edit: since it has been asked what did I `ls`, in the end I just did:

```
cd miniconda3
ls
```

to get:

```
ls: cannot access LICENSE.txt: No such file or directory
bin  conda-meta  envs  include  lib  LICENSE.txt  pkgs  share  ssl
```

Also `lsof miniconda3` doesn't output anything

Comment: Did you try `sudo rm -rf` or `sudo rm -Rf`?

Comment: `rm` shouldn't care if directory is empty or not. Is `rm` alias to `rmdir` on your system? Post output of `type rm`.

Comment: Are you currently running a program installed via `conda` in some other terminal?

Comment: I cannot sudo and I'm not running any program installed via conda. With 'type rm' I get: 'rm is hashed (/usr/bin/rm)'

Comment: @tuphio: Hmm, ok. What OS are you using - something Linux-based, BSD, MAC, something different? What does `rm --version` say?

Comment: Show us what you did. Eluding to it is not enough. e.g. what did you `ls`?

Comment: It's Scientific Linux. The version of rm is the following:

rm (GNU coreutils) 8.22
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Paul Rubin, David MacKenzie, Richard M. Stallman,
and Jim Meyering.

Comment: @tuphio: Post output of `lsof miniconda3`

Comment: @tuphio: I don't understand you edit. Are you trying to say that `miniconda3` directory is empty?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I corrected now with the output to ls

Comment: @tuphio: Why have you posted the same thing twice?

Comment: @tuphio: try `sudo lsof miniconda3`. If it returns nothing then I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I don't have the privileges to sudo unfortunately

Comment: @tuphio: if the system you're running on is also used by other users at the same time it's very possible that some processes keep creating new directories when `rm` is already running

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I'm not sure about that, other users cannot access my user's folder

Comment: @tupio: root can

Comment: To me it looks like filesystem corruption. A filesystem check sounds like a good measure. I've seen that behaviour in failing SD cards. The system thinks the file has been erased, but it is not, because the underlying filesystem is no longer sane.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk rm -r is different. It recurses down the tree deleting files, and back up deleting the directories. If it fails to rm a file, it is not permitted to rm the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eduardo suggested, the problem was actually that the filesystem was corrupted